# how to let visitor to a site enter a url and have that input be produced in framed box within same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter, embed

I'm relatively new to the site and the programming side of things. I searched for this question but don't believe I necessarily found it (and if I did then I had difficulty deciphering the answer), so apologies if this is a repeat and/or for my potential lack of understanding.

I was wondering how I would go about creating a box within a page that would allow a visitor to the site the chance to type a url into the box and have that page appear within the box, while ensuring the user stays on the same page within my website.

For instance, a user on the page would type in a url to a tweet and that tweet would appear within a rectangular frame on the site, rather than opening or linking to a new page. Displaying within the box is important. Thank you!

Comment: Use an iframe and set its src attribute as the url typed in the input field using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can accept the URL as user input with a form, and set the source of an iframe to show the content.

Related: [How do I let a user input a video url and have the video show on the same page upon submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637769/how-do-i-let-a-user-input-a-video-url-and-have-the-video-show-on-the-same-page-u?rq=1)